# using a static function without an instance of the class, in c++

Tags: c++, static

i have a class with static functions.
i need to use the functions without creating an instance of the class.

is it possible?

Answer (score 17):

Sure:

```
class A {
   public:
      static void f();
};

...

A::f();    // call function
```

Answer (score 1):

No problem at all, thats the point of them.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use the singleton design pattern: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#C.2B.2B](http://wiki)